# use phpmailer\phpmailer\PHPMailer throws 'the import ... cannot be resolved

Tags: php, namespaces, phpmailer

I have seen quite a few Q&As around this but it appears to me that their issue is a step further.

All objects after the `use` statement are underlined in red within the Eclipse IDE showing the error
`the import phpmailer\phpmailer\PHPMailer cannot be resolved`.

```php
<?php 
use phpmailer\phpmailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require '/Users/me/eclipse/php-2021-09/vendor/autoload.php';
```

You may notice `phpmailer\phpmailer\...` vs `PHPMailer\PHPMailer\` This is because all examples show capital letters while composer installed it to phpmailer\phpmailer. Anyways, both versions show errors.

Comment: Did you install from composer? Or manually do the setup? If manually, did you insert the require statements shown in the docs? See https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer. Maybe you can give some extra info that might be helpfull. Like php version, phpmailer version, server type etc. Also try to remove the first `use`, see if the SMTP `use` also gives error, or if it is just the `phpMailer` one.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Allart. First I tried with a manual set-up including the require statements. Then I tried it with composer, what you can see now (and changed the first use`argument to capital letters again). I started off with the `vendor` folder lateral to the project folder, now I reinstalled it with `composer` underneath the project folder (see my similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69720091/adding-a-library-to-php-with-composer-fails-in-eclipse). php 7.3.24, phpmailer 6.5, MAMP local host, Eclipse 2021-09 (4.21.0), anything else?

Answer (score 0):

It’s case sensitive, should be:

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
```

Composer package names are not the same thing as namespaces, and they are also different to path names.

Comment: but this didn't work in the first place. That is why I changed it to lower case, So I started off with `use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;`. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: The capital letters in the use statement are definitely correct. That path to the composer autoloader is suspicious; it looks like it’s loading from an IDE configuration folder rather than your project, so you may be configuring your packages in one place and loading them from another.

Comment: That is how it looks like on a Mac... Eclipse is in the path because I have everything related to the web page (php library etc) stored there. But what you are saying is, when those files are recognized correctly, Eclipse should get a name space out of there? I receive the error before running any script, just by looking to the editor

Comment: I just replaced the absolute with a relative path `require '/../../php-2021-09/vendor/autoload.php';` and I also `require`d Exception.php, PHPMailer.php and SMTP.php distinctly - no change

Comment: That’s not a relative path. Can you show the contents of that folder in your question?